# How to evaluate a function giving a value in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

(F n m l f g): n and m are natural numbers, l a list of numbers, f and g functions that take a numeric parameter and return a number. The F function should return:

[image]

I need to program this function in scheme. And I have developed a function for the product but not how to perform the evaluation of the role, I tried with the eval command but not worked yet

Any help on how to do?

Comment: Your question is very confusing, and I have no idea what most of it is talking about. Can you clarify it? Is English not your first language?

Comment: The English is not my first language, I rewrote now, I hope this a little more understandable.

Comment: I figured that's what your question was about. You don't need to use `eval` at all. Please don't use `eval` unless you really have to. You can invoke functions `f` and `g` by just calling them, no `eval` needed. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a straightforward translation of your formula to Racket:

```
(define (F n m l f g)
  (for/sum ([i (in-range 1 (add1 n))])
    (- (f (expt m i))
       (g (for/product ([j (in-list l)])
            (expt j i))))))
```

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I have a problem when I try for example with this command: (F1 2 '(2 3 4) (+ x 1) (x - 1)) gives me this error: application: not a procedure; How do I have to write the functions that does not return an error?

Comment: @Jac You have to use `(F 1 2 '(2 3 4) (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (x) (- x 1)))` (or just `(F 1 2 '(2 3 4) add1 sub1)`), not the notation you have.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thank you very much